# Bootstrap pagination - how to remove gap/ space below the items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

There is a strange gap/ space below the pagination items in Bootstrap. How can I remove it?

[image]

My code:

```
<header role="navigation">

  <!-- justify-content-end is only available on bootstrap 4 -->
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-lg justify-content-end">
      <li id="high1" class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#anchor-1">1</a></li>
      <li id="high2" class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#anchor-2">2</a></li>
      <li id="high3" class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#anchor-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header > nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>span {
  border: none;
  color: #000;
}

.pagination>li:first-child>a, .pagination>li:first-child>span,
.pagination>li:last-child>a, .pagination>li:last-child>span {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRYaMG)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header > nav {font-size: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line-height controls this gap, just change as appropriate.

```
header > nav { line-height: 0.8; }
```

Just be careful on inheritance. If anything inherits this line-height then it may cause issues further down.